# undefined method 'each' when accessing articles from navbar in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I need to be able to access articles through the navbar dropdown.

in my `views/application/_navbar.html.erb`I have the code snipped below. It is not working and I always get this error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`

when I hit the link in the dropdown the app goes to the right path `http://localhost:3000/lcas/1`

I only need to be able to access the first article in each category so `http://localhost:3000/lcas/1` is the right path for the first link in the dropdown

code from `views/application/_navbar.html.erb`

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <% @lcas.each do |lca| %>
            <li><%= link_to lca.title, lca_path(lca) %></li>
          <% end %>
           <% @energy_analyses.each do |energy_analysis| %>
            <li><%=link_to energy_analysis.title, energy_analysis_path(energy_analysis)  %></li>
           <% end %> 
           <% @green_accountings.each do |green_accounting| %>
            <li><%= link_to green_accounting.title, green_accounting_path(green_accounting) %></li>
            <% end %>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">something</a></li>
            </ul>
```

On my `index.html.erb`I have basically the same code and there it works.

```
<% @lcas.each do |lca| %>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks icons" aria-hidden="true"> </span>
             <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"><%= link_to lca.title, lca_path(lca) %></h3>
             </div>   
      </div>
      <% end %>
```

I've tried to add

```
@lcas = Lca.all
@energy_analyses = EnergyAnalysis.all
@green_accountings = GreenAccounting.all
```

to the `application_controller.rb` but with out any success.

here is  the `lcas_controller.rb`

```
class LcasController < InheritedResources::Base

 private

 def lca_params
  params.require(:lca).permit(:title, :body, :image)
 end
end
```

It would be very nice if someone could guide me through this.

Comment: Which view file is the dropdown menu code in?

Comment: its in views/application/_navbar.html.erb

Comment: Try adding a `before_action` to your `application_controller.rb` which sets the instance variables, instead of placing the instance variable code directly inside the class definition.

Comment: You're getting the `nil` error most likely because the instance variables haven't been set in the right place.

Comment: If the the navbar is always present then these instance variables must always be present as well. Not just in the LcasController but globally as @cobaltsoda suggested application_controller will do this for you but please understand that every page load will take a hit three fold to load these instance variables

Comment: it would help a lot to show the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need few things:
Set a before_action method for those variables in application_controller.rb to make sure each other controller calls it and pass the variable to their corresponding view:

```
before_action :set_vars

    def set_vars
     @lcas = Lca.all
     @energy_analyses = EnergyAnalysis.all
     @green_accountings = GreenAccounting.all
    end
```

Now you should be able to access @lcas from your partial, but using instance variables in partials is violating MVC, so you should pass locals to it:

```
<%= render 'application/navbar', :lcas => @lcas %>
```

Not sure how to pass multiple locals, maybe like this:

```
  <%= render 'shared/navbar', locals: {:lcas => @lcas, :energy => @energy_analyses, :green => @green_accountings} %>
```

And of course, don't use @ in partial if passing locals:

```
   <% energy.each do |energy_analysis| %>
```